# How can there be two products with same remainder when divided with 100

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For   $a_i,b_j \space \epsilon \space \space \{ 1..100 \} ,\   i \neq j$ ,how can we prove that there exists two products with same remainder  $a_i * b_j \space mod \space 100$ . ie $a_1*b_1 mod  \ 100 \equiv a_2 * b_2 mod\ 100  $. where $\{a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2\}$ be some arbitary number in the set {1..100}.

Comment: How many $a_i$ and $b_j$ are there ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy just 2, ie pick 2 numbers (a,b)  in the set 1..100 .Then do  a*b mod 100. How can we prove that there exists another two number x,y in set 1..100 such that their product x*y mod 100 gives the same remainder as a*b mod 100 ??

Comment: @ShuXiaoLi i know that there are two such number but how will you proceed with a proof for this.Thanks

Comment: Use pegion-hole principle! @ShuXiaoLi: No, that is for contradicting a fact. But if you need to prove, you have to generalize it.

Comment: You have $\,100\,$ elements $\,0,1,\ldots 99\,$ to fill the $\,100^2$ boxes in the multiplication table mod $100.\,$ Hence some element must occur twice in the multiplication table since $\, 100 < 100^2.\ \ $

Comment: @prajul, we need to show $a_i\cdot b_j\equiv a_k\cdot b_l\pmod{ 100}$ for each pair of $i,j$   right?

Comment: @MathGems being  $ 100 < 100^2 $ how will it ensure that there will be two elements same in that table ?

Comment: If not then you'd have a bijection from a set of $\,100\,$ elements onto a set $\,100^2\,$ elements (or $100^2/2$ counting commutativity).

Comment: @labbhattacharjee yes,take any two  number's between 1..100 and its modulo with 100. How to prove that there will be another pair with same remainder ?

Comment: Look at the two answers below. Do they satisfy your need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $(10x+a)(10y+b)\equiv10(a\cdot y+b\cdot x)+ab\pmod{100}\equiv ab\pmod{100}$ if $10\mid(a\cdot y+b\cdot x)$

Similarly, $(10x-a)(10y-b)\equiv ab\pmod{100}$ if $10\mid(a\cdot y+b\cdot x)$

So we need to find $x,y$ such that $10x\pm a\ne a, 10y\pm a\ne a$  and $10\mid(a\cdot y+b\cdot x)$

---

Again  $(10x+a)(10y+b)\equiv(10x-a)(10y-b)\pmod{100}$ if $5\mid(a\cdot y+b\cdot x)$

Comment: Seems more finer than mine. How bout multiplying each products? Like, if $a_1b_1 \equiv k \mod 100$ and $a_2b_2 \equiv k \mod 100$, then $a_1a_2b_1b_2$ will $k^2 \ mod 100 $.? Can we try prove that?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee dosent this reduce to finding $xb\  mod\  10 \equiv ya\  mod\  10 $ ? instead of our earlier concept of finding equivalency using 100.Does the above answer prove problem or create another instance of the same problem ??

Comment: @prajul, I've chosen the numbers to be $(a,b);(10x\pm a),(10y\pm b)$ in case1 and $(10x+a,10y+b);(10x-a,10y-b)$ in case2

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the $100$ products $a_ib_i$ leave $100$ different remainders when divided by 100.

Then $50$ of the products must be odd and the remaining $50$ must be even since their remainders must now be a permutation of $1,2,3,...100$. The $50$ odd products use up all the $50$ odd $a_i$ and odd $b_i$.

Hence the even products are products of two even numbers, and are therefore divisible by $4$.

But then none of the products will be of form $4k+2$, which gives a contradiction. Therefore, there exists two products with same remainder.